# jnlp-file for Java Webstart and Java Applet at the same time

Tags: java, jar, applet, jnlp

Can i use the same jnlp file to deploy a webstart application as well as the applet version of the same application?

In other words, can a jnlp-file contain both an application-desc tag as well as an applet-desc tag?

I have tried it, but I am getting some errors, maybe i did something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can put the bulk of your code in an extension and reference that from both the applet jnlp and the application jnlp.